# Smack 4.2 create user service-unavailable

Tags: android, ejabberd, smack

I am using Smack 4.2 and developing an android client (debugging on real device connected via USB). Managed to connect to a ejabberd server on a VirtualBox.

Fyi, in ejabberd.yml, I have uncommented the **mod_register**, set **registration_timeout:infinity**, set **register -allow**, and **trusted_network: -allow, all**.

So, I still got an exception "service-unavailable", from the debug trace and below are my snippets.

```
    DomainBareJid serviceName = JidCreate.domainBareFrom("localhost");

    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder builder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    builder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
    builder.setXmppDomain(serviceName);
    builder.setHostAddress(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.148"));
    builder.setPort(5222);
    builder.setDebuggerEnabled(true);

    xmppConn = new XMPPTCPConnection( builder.build());
    xmppConn.connect();

    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(xmppConn);
    try {
        if (accountManager.supportsAccountCreation()) {
            accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
            accountManager.createAccount( Localpart.from("username"), "password");
        }
    }
```

Thank you if anyone could point me to the right direction and what am I missing here?

Comment: are u doing xmppConn.login() ??

Comment: Yes. I am doing the login. Thank you Moulesh. Just got it working an hour ago!

I was struggling to make the mod_register work -in the ejabberd.yml file. The configuration file is very sensitive to spaces and tabs. So I remove/delete the "dirty" file. Then copy the original file and re-do the mod_register line, until it work.

Comment: it's not secure to let account creation from client side. No check if it's a robot, or valid info, ... 
I suggest you always user API for resgistration, restrict its execution to localhost and write solid backend verification before registration.